# "very low quality flag" declined - is that justified?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104218/6464308) as "very low quality" because it just copied (non-working) code from the question without any additional comment or statement. I wrote a comment to indicate this.

> [image]

The flag was declined with the comment: "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". The answer has been deleted since, so this question is not a call for action, but I'd like to know if I really did something wrong there.

I read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/why-were-these-very-low-quality-flags-declined/189373#189373) to a similar question, and the criterion stated there was:

> If I'm not comfortable outright deleting a post, I'm going to decline the VLQ flag.

It seems like this was a good description of the case in question. Nothing is lost by deleting that answer.

Comment: This wouldn't have come across in a VLQ if I am honest. You would have been better off raising a custom mod flag and explaining it's a copy pasta. The response you got, in my opinion, is correct. The mod would certainly not looked at the question to see if it's a copy pasta, not that they would know to look for that, and they may well have no read the comments (not sure if they are displayed in their review queue).

Comment: VLQ is for things that don't even look like answers. Essentially, complete gibberish. Anything that *resembles* an answer is not VLQ-flag worthy. If it's technically inaccurate or wrong, that's outside the purview of the flag.

Comment: That's not even copy pasted code. It may be completely wrong, but there are several differences from the original code in the question. Even as a custom flag, there were ample reasons to decline the flag. Just use your votes, those are the right tool for these situations.

Comment: If I would check this in the VLQ queue, I would first make sure that both codes are identical, first few words in question `merge into Mytable WITH`, first few words in answer `MERGE Mytable dst USING`. They are not the same.

Comment: The code has been the same in the first revision, but the question has been modified before the flag got declined. Unfortunately, reviewers don't see the question revision when the answer was flagged, but only the current revision at the time of review.

Comment: sorry to say it is imho a very low quality answer, but not regulated by the rules, leave a comment and downvote it

Comment: "but I'd like to know if I really did something wrong there" - Not really. The VLQ flag is a trap which when you look long enough at it might seem like the hammer to all nails and makes you completely forget there is a downvote button. I mean, what is the difference between "low quality" and "very low quality"? There is no standard measure for it. But in reality only very rarely should it actually be used because it means VERY low quality, to the point of not being comprehensible. It's how Stack Overflow keeps you on your toes.

Comment: Just so you have an answer from a moderator…That's not a valid use of the VLQ flag. What you flagged does, in fact, look like an answer, at least upon first inspection. When that is true, you should not use the VLQ flag. If additional explanation/investigation is needed to understand the problem(s) with the answer, then you need to raise a custom flag on it. VLQ means "this is obvious garbage that needs to be immediately deleted". Admittedly, different mods have different thresholds for "obvious garbage", and thus deviate somewhat in handling of VLQ, but none of us would have seen this as VLQ.

Comment: @Gimby The difference between "low quality" and "very low quality" is meant to be whether the post can be edited, or whether it needs to be immediately deleted. I agree with and endorse the rest of your comment.